# New car AWD tire replacement

Tags: tires, mazda, wheels, awd, replacements

I have a 2016.5 Mazda CX5 AWD which have run 1900 miles till now. Right front tire got a nail puncture. The nail is at the corner of the tire. Tire replacement shop told as nail is at side tire cannot be mended and it has to be replaced. Also, as it is AWD so all 4 tires need to be replaced.

My question is car is just 4 months old with 1900 miles, will it require all 4 replacement or only 1 will do?

Answer (score 3):

At 1900 miles, you'll only need to replace one tire.

Make sure the new tire is IDENTICAL to the other three. Ask the shop to measure the tread wear on the other tires, and to shave the new tire if the difference is outside the limits allowed. I think at 1900 miles, you won't even need to shave it.

If the tire replacement shop gives you a strange look when you ask them to consider shaving the tire, you're in the wrong tire shop. Put the donut spare on and go somewhere else.

If the tire replacement shop tells you that it's not possible to get an identical match for the tire, then again you're in the wrong place. Put the donut spare on and drive to the dealer.

Actually, it may be worth going to the dealer anyway; there may be some sort of warranty in place on the tires for a short while, or they may give you a goodwill benefit and cut you a deal on that new tire.

Comment: Sounds a bit strange that you on one hand point out that the new tire must be IDENTICAL to the other three, but at the same time suggest putting the donut spare on (which certainly isn't identical) and going somewhere else.

Comment: @juhist There is a big difference between putting the spare on and driving "carefully" a fairly short distance (e.g. 10 miles) to "somewhere else", compared with replacing a tire and expecting the thrash the car up and down a freeway for 10,000 miles before you even need to check the air pressure!

Comment: Since its a nail puncture, a warranty won't cover it (new cars don't usually come with a road hazard warranty). Purchase seems the only option.

Comment: @juhist: I certainly wouldn't recommend driving 30,000 miles with the donut on - that would trash the differential. Going to the tire store would be OK.

Comment: @PeteCon: and it would also trash the donut which is usually rated for limited speeds and limited distances.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the reason to replace all 4 is because if all 4 tires are worn, then putting on one new tire which will be slightly taller due to it not being worn will cause the awd to "activate " causing  some weird driving concerns. BUT if all 4 tires only have 1900 miles you should be ok if you get the same brand of tire. Do you have a full size spare? Also read your owners manual.